# What changes should I do to my cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1 project to run it on iPhone 5?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios6, iphone-5

I've been developing a cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1 game project and have been testing it on an iPhone 4.

I'll soon be getting an iPhone 5. I just updated Xcode to 4.5.2.

Will my project be able to at least run on the iPhone 5 immediately? Or is there a major change I must do in my project? As in, is something going to crash when I try to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do anything, the app will run on iPhone 5 at the original resolution. Meaning there will be empty (black) space on the sides.

Once you add an image named `Default-586h@2x.png` with dimensions 640x1136 then your app will use the entire width of the iPhone 5 screen. You will have to adapt your layout to support the iPhone 5 screen size.

Comment: Ah, so there are no technical issues etc? I think I heard somewhere that were was an orientation-related thing...

Comment: By the way, I am using 1.0.1, not 1.1.0. I noticed that 1.1.0 says "iPhone 5 support". So now I'm a bit lost. Is 1.0.1 okay?

Comment: @Omega 1.0.1 will work fine as answered here, without further changes.

Comment: Orientation issues are related to iOS 6 which handles rotation differently. This whole "iPhone 5 support" is bollocks. ;) The Xcode project templates now include the Default-586h@2x.png file, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to run on the iphone 5 immediately but it will probably be letter boxed since im guessing it does not support a taller screen size yet.